# Using Bloom to generate binaries for multiple packages

Tags: ros, binaries, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to use bloom to generate binaries for a repository containing multiple packages that are interdependent. However, I don't want to make the packages public (i.e. push to the build farm and make a PR). From my understanding, this leaves me in a gap within bloom.

Since I don't want the package public, `bloom-release` isn't an option for me, but just running `bloom-generate` as explained in [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/173804/generate-deb-from-ros-package/) doesn't work because `rosdep` is not aware of the other packages.

Is there a way to bridge this gap such that I can obtain binaries for all my packages without pushing to the build farm?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230104/using-bloom-to-generate-binaries-for-multiple-packages/) by [skycoop](https://answers.ros.org/users/26389/skycoop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a custom rosdistro: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/master/doc/custom_rosdistro.rst

That will make sure your packages are in the rosdep database after releasing them. Also you could just have a local rosdep file which defined translations from your package names to the equivalent debian package names. See: http://answers.ros.org/question/50660/custom-rosdep-rules/

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1